# Page Reloads After Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am doing a Single Page Application using asp.net MVC

When I'm posting to the server from Ajax, The Web API validates the parameters sent, then returns a Json String. Here's the function in my Web API

```
Public Class VerifyReturn
    Public SerBool As String
    Public SerMessage As String
    Public TextBool As String
    Public TextMessage As String
End Class

<HttpPost>
Public Function ValidateParam(ByVal ser As Integer, ByVal content As String) As List(Of VerifyReturn)
    Dim ErrorsJson As String = ""
    Dim Errors As Boolean = False


    Try
        If Not ser = Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(ser) = True Then  
            ErrorsJson &= "[{""SerBool"":""0"",""SerMessage"":"""","
        Else
            ErrorsJson &= "[{""SerBool"":""1"",""SerMessage"":""Not Valid."","
            Errors = True
        End If

       If Not content Is Nothing AndAlso content.Length < 151 Then
            ErrorsJson &= """TextBool"":""0"",""TextMessage"":""""}]"
       Else
            ErrorsJson &= """TextBool"":""1"",""TextMessage"":""Content Too Large.""}]"
            Errors = True
        End If

        Dim ReturnJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of VerifyReturn))(ErrorsJson)
        Return ReturnJson


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

This is my Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#BtnInsert').click(function () {

           $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/api/ContentM/ValidateParam?ser=")' + $('#SerList').val() + ("&content=") + $('#TxtContent').val(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (responseData) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {

                            If(responseData[i].TextBool == '1')
                            {
                                $('#LblErrors').val(responseData[i].TextMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
          });
      });
```

The API function is being triggered and the procedure **server side** is going fine,

But when the ajax call finishes, the page **reloads** and I see nothing in my $('#LblErrors') Label.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are executing your AJAX request on the click of an `a` element or form submission you may need to stop those actions completing by using `preventDefault()` on the event. If you post more of your JS code it would help.

Comment: provide more code or create a fiddle..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please check now.

Comment: What type of element is `#btnInsert`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan <button id="BtnInsert">Insert</button>

Comment: I'm not nearly as good as most of these guys, but would putting "return false" at the end of the JS function stop the postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, using `<button></button>` on HTML, a form is submitted automatically. That might be your problem. One way to solve it is putting a `return false` as our friend said above. So this is how it should be: `<button id="BtnInsert" onclick="return false">Insert</button>`. Another way is preventing the automatic submitting inside your `.click(function(e)` function using `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#BtnInsert').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/api/ContentM/ValidateParam?ser=")' + $('#SerList').val() + ("&content=") + $('#TxtContent').val(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (responseData) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {

                        If(responseData[i].TextBool == '1')
                        {
                            $('#LblErrors').val(responseData[i].TextMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
      });
  });
```